# Axis ticks and labels for time with base R

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, plot

I'm looking for similar behavior as

```
scale_x_datetime(labels=date_format("%H:%M", tz="UTC"),
                 breaks=date_breaks(breaks))
```

in ggplot with any break type of "5 mins", "30 mins", "1 hours" and so on **for base R plots**.

I currently use

```
f <- function(x) as.POSIXct(levels(cut(x, breaks)))
axis(1, at=f(data$Time), labels=format(f(data$Time), "%H:%M"))
```

but the outcome isn't always pretty depending on data time values.
For example sometimes with 5 minute intervals the ticks/labels might be 9:01, 9:06, 9:11, ... instead of 9:00, 9:05, 9:10, ... what is my goal and what I get with ggplot.

Does anyone have a nice solution for this?

Example:

```
library("ggplot2")

N <- 3e3
time <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-12-12 8:51:43 UTC", tz="UTC"), length.out=N, by="1 sec")
data <- data.frame(Time=time, Value=rnorm(N))

breaks <- "5 mins"

# base
plot(x=data$Time, y=data$Value, xaxt="n")

f <- function(x) as.POSIXct(levels(cut(x, breaks)))
axis(1, at=f(data$Time), labels=format(f(data$Time), "%H:%M"))


# ggplot
p <- ggplot(data) + geom_point(aes(x=Time, y=Value)) +
  scale_x_datetime(labels=date_format("%H:%M", tz="UTC"),
                   breaks=date_breaks(breaks))

p
```

Comment: Hi @Tsingis, could you post a reproducible example (i.e. include a sample dataset and your existing code). I'll take a look at this for you and see what I can do.

Comment: You could use `scale_x_continuous(name, breaks, labels, limits, trans)` or `scale_x_discrete(name, breaks, labels, limits)` depending on your variable type. For example, for limits you can set a `min` and `max`, if you set `min` to 9:00 and then set `breaks` to 0:05 you should get your desired output. But I can't say much more when I can't see the data and play with it.

Comment: Example coming up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function `roundPOSIXt` in package [`datetimeutils`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=datetimeutils) (which I maintain). It may do what you want.

```
library("datetimeutils")

roundPOSIXt(Sys.time(), interval = "10 min", up = FALSE)
## [1] "2018-12-14 10:40:00 CET"

roundPOSIXt(Sys.time(), interval = "10 min", up = TRUE)
## [1] "2018-12-14 10:50:00 CET"
```

So for your example:

```
N <- 3e3
time <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-12-12 8:51:43 UTC", tz = "UTC"),
            length.out = N, by = "1 sec")
data <- data.frame(Time = time, Value = rnorm(N))

fmt <- function(x, breaks)
    unique(roundPOSIXt(x, "5 mins"))

plot(x = data$Time, y = data$Value, xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = fmt(data$Time),
     labels = format(fmt(data$Time), "%H:%M"))
```

Comment: If it works for my example it should also work on my real data.